# Error al borrar un registro en laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

En mi siguiente código, quiero eliminar una fotografia del sistema mediante AJAX pero a la hora de hacer la petición, me arroja el anterior error

> Error: The requested method DELETE is not allowed for the URL

mi código es el siguiente

**Route:**

```
Route::delete('tienda/productos/eliminarimagen/{id}', 'TiendaController@destroy')
```

**Controlador:**

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    $this->connection->db_connection();

    $producto = VipArchivo::find($id);
    $producto->delete();

    Session::flash('message', 'Imagen eliminada');
    return Redirect::to('tienda/productos/edit/'.$id.'');
}
```

Y el **AJAX:**

```
function eliminaImg(values)
{
    var id_foto = values;
    var route = 'http://localhost/tienda/productos/eliminarimagen/'+id_foto+'';
    var token = $('#token').val();
    swal({
        title: "Eliminar foto",
        text: "¿Está seguro de eliminar esta foto?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Sí, eliminar!",
        cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
        closeOnConfirm: false },
        function(){
            console.log(id_foto);
            $.ajax({
                url:route,
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN':token},
                type:'DELETE',
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(){
                    console.log('eliminó');
                }

            })
        });
}
```

Comment: tengo mis dudas tengo tiempo que no programo en laravel pero por que haces un redirect cuando debes retornar un json? ejecuta en la raiz del proyecto por consola php artisan route:list se deben de ver las url que tiene el routes

Comment: Lo de retornar un redirect, es meramente de prueba, visto que ni siquiera entra al function del controlador, lo vi irrelevante si permanecia ahi o no, o me equivoco?

Comment: primero verifica si tienes la ruta cargada con el comando php artisan route:list

Comment: Lo hice, y si está creada

Comment: haz la prueba desde postman puede que falte agregar mas parametro a tu header

Comment: ya vi el error! , es tu version de jquery hasta la 1.9 usa el type ahora cambio a method lo que quiero decir es que cambies el `type:'DELETE',` por `method: 'DELETE',`

Comment: @JackNavaRow, Lo intenté, arroja el mismo error, estoy por tirar la toalla

Comment: pero por postman?? probastes el cambio que te dije de cambiar la palabra type por method?

Comment: asi es, cambie a method, y en postman no muestra nada ,as de lo regular

Comment: quiere decir que en postman funciona algo esta mal en ajax

Comment: $.ajax({
    url: '/v1/object/3.json',
    method: 'DELETE',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(result) {
        // handle success
    },
    error: function(request,msg,error) {
        // handle failure
    }
}); intena algo asi a ver

Comment: Al parecer la petición DELETE es el problema, no se puede hacer peticiones ascincronas por algo llamado cross domain (el cual por mi novatez desconozco)

Comment: es tu ruta absoluta intenta solo tienda/productos/eliminarimagen/'+id_foto+'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede suceder porque no tienes habilitado el método DELETE en CORS.
Suponiendo que tienes una versión de laravel superior a 5.0.

Lo que debes hacer es crear un middleware Cors `php artisan make:middleware Cors`

Abre el archivo App->Http->Middleware->Cors.php que se creó, y en la función **handle** define lo siguiente

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');

    }
```

Puedes eliminar los métodos que no te sean útiles, la que te es útil ahora es **DELETE**

En el archivo App -> Http -> Kernel.php
sitúate en **$middleware** y agrega la siguiente línea:  `\App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,`

dentro de **$routeMiddleware** agrega la siguiente linea

```
'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class
```

Por último debes definir el middleware a utilizar agrupando las rutas a las que deseas acceder por los métodos que necesitas, sea en **api o web**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api', 'cors'] ...//el resto de tu código
```